# What is alternate of @import url("http://abc") in style sheet

Tags: css, sitecore, bundling-and-minification, sitecore8, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Actually we have one global.css style sheet in which we are using `@import url("http://fonts.net/sample.css?type=cssandid=123")` for fonts.

But it's creating issues in Bundling & minification so I got following solutions:
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

and I replace @import with  element

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://fonts.net/sample.css?type=cssandid=123'>
```

even after this I'm getting CSS errors as I checked in CSS Lint(http://csslint.net/) and not getting real UI effect as with @import.

Do we have any other solutions for this?

Environment: VS2015 , MVC 5.2 , sitecore 8.1

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Sukhi I put the url in browser and it showed me 404 error. So does the url returns css at all?

Comment: that is not actual URL...I put that only for our understanding

Answer (score -1):

Hope you found the solution since you posted this question

What you can do, to avoid the @import url('yourCssUrlHere') is simply copy/paste the URL on your browser and then copy/past the CSS that is displayed.

And then simply replace the @import by the CSS you just copied.

Most of the time if the import is a font, there will be other references to .woff or .woff2 files.
Just download them and store those files somewhere on your project folder and just add their absolute link on all the url() fields.

That way, you use external fonts or stylesheets, but internally, without request them outside of your website.